# Unknown factor in answer

Tags: java, sum-of-digits

I can't find the problem with what I wrote. I am attempting Project Euler #16, where I need to sum all digits of 2^1000. My program works with small numbers, but as numbers get around 18 digits or so, it breaks. Any help?

```
public static double digit(double n){

    return n % 10;

}

public static double sumofDigits(double n){

    double sum = 0;

    while(n > 1){

        sum += digit(n);
        n = Math.floor(n/10);

    }

    return sum;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double x = Math.pow(2,1000);

    double y = 22222222222222222222d;

    System.out.println(sumofDigits(x));

            System.out.println(sumofDigits(y));

}
```

}

Comment: What does "it breaks" mean? Do you have an error? What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A double has an accuracy of about 16 decimal digits. Since 2 power 1000 has much more digits (about 300) you simply can not work with a double.

Have a look at the BigInteger class.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `double` here: they have a limited precision only. (see [Java primitive datatypes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html))

So `Math.pow(2,1000)`only computes some (first) digits and the exponent.

You have to use some library which handles arbitrary long integers. (e.g. [biginteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html))

Answer (score 0):

I got it now. I've replaced all the doubles here with a BigDecimal object representing that decimal number so that decimal accuracy && size of # is achieved. Thanks everyone.